# Angular Material: How do I apply custom themed typography to a CSS class outside of the theme file?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have a custom theme file which I import into my main `style` file. Elsewhere in my app I have encapsulated component scss. Inside those scss files I am doing something like:

`.heading-thing {
    @include mat-typography-level-to-styles($config, subheading-2);
  }`

The problem here, is `$config` is defined in my theme file and I don't know how to access it. What I **really** want is a mixin that does something like

`.heading-thing {
    @include mat-typography-apply-theme-style(subheading-2);
  }`

Is the correct way of doing this to use `@extend .mat-subheading-2;`? Or is there a better way with a mixin?

Comment: One way to do this could be to simply define your typography in a separate partial file `_app-typography.scss/sass` and then import it as needed

Comment: I am not sure that really achieves what I am after. I want to simply apply heading styles to a specific element without having to apply the `heading` class to the HTML element. I don't want to import a whole partial across multiple encapsulated sass files, seems like this would lead to bloat. Maybe I've misunderstood what you are saying?

Answer (score 2):

There's an easy way to get the config that is a cheat, and there's a 'correct' way.

The easy way is to simply create it:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
$config: mat-typography-config();
```

That's described [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/typography#material-typography-in-your-custom-css). If you've customized the typography, this won't work. But you could create your own function to return your custom config.

The 'correct' way is to implement typography customization the same way that you implement [theming customization](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components). Create a mixin that applies the typography styling, and include that mixin in a theming file for your component. Something like:

src/app/components/my-component/_my-component-theme.scss

```
@mixin my-component-typography($config) {

  .heading-thing {
    @include mat-typography-level-to-styles($config, subheading-2);
  }
}
```

This would need to be called from your global sass, where the typography config is passed in to the mixin:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

/* gui theming and typography mixins and globals */
@import 'src/app/components/my-component/my-component-theme';

$config: mat-typography-config(); // or customize
@include angular-material-typography($config);

/* customize components */
@include my-component-typography($config);
```

You'll have to change whatever you need to customize your typography.

This is what Angular Material does, and as you probably see it mirrors how theming is customized. See their code [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/8050f633b56b6c048fc72dad2ab79304afdfad19/src/lib/core/typography/_all-typography.scss).

As for 'bloat', remember that SASS is compiled down to CSS, and the compiler should discard anything unused.